# capistrano 3.0.1 Don't know how to build task 'starting' when using capistrano/rails/assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, asset-pipeline

When trying to deploy with Capistrano 3.0.1 I get the following error:

```
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'starting'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:5:in `before'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.0/lib/capistrano/rails/assets.rb:1:in `load'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.0/lib/capistrano/rails/assets.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/Documents/rails/shop/Capfile:18:in `require'
/Users/user/Documents/rails/shop/Capfile:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:22:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This seems to have started when I uncommented the require rows for loading assets and performing migrations in the Capfile:

```
  # Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
  require 'capistrano/setup'

  # Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
  #
  # require 'capistrano/rvm'
  # require 'capistrano/rbenv'
  # require 'capistrano/chruby'
  # require 'capistrano/bundler'
  require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
  require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

  # Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
  Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

and adding the gems to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'capistrano',  '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.0'
```

It's like the required assets are loaded before the default capistrano tasks so they fail because a the time of loading the `starting` is not yet defined. I'm not sure how to fix this,

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Don't know how to build task" errors can be caused by having the 'require' lines in the *wrong order* in the Capfile.

Answer (score 5):

The `Capfile` was missing the line:

```
 require 'capistrano/deploy'
```

this is responsible of loading the deployment tasks.

Missing that requirement the tasks won't be loaded and they will be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try capistrano from master, and the rails gem from master too.

There's a new release of both pending, so might be best to jump the gun:

```
gem 'capistrano', github: 'capistrano/capistrano', ref: 'master'
gem 'capistrano-rails', github: 'capistrano/rails', ref: 'master'
```

Comment: thanks, that gives no improvement, now it stops with: `Don't know how to build task 'deploy:updated'`, called from: 

`/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/rails-e12513279ad4/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:48:in `block in <top (required)>'`

Comment: I figured that my Capfile was missing the `require 'capistrano/deploy'
` line, that I must have deleted accidentally, this was preventing Capistrano from loading the tasks. so indeed they weren't found when declaring `after` and `before` them.

Answer (score -1):

I did run `cap -T` and got the same error. I was already heading out for google looking for solutions, until I realized that the project was not set up for capistrano at all.